# python regex: replacing <number>st, <number>nd, <number>th etc in a adress with a single sub

Tags: python, regex

I have many adresses like "East 19th Street" or "West 141st Street" and I would like to remove the "th" and the "st" in a single call to re.sub.

```
re.sub("(\d+)st|(\d+)nd|(\d+)rd|(\d+)th", "g<1>", "East 19th Street")
```

doesn't work because it is not always the first gorup which is caught

I could chain the subs but it is dirty. 
Help appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
re.sub(r"(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)\b", r"\1", str)
```

or better

```
re.sub(r"(?<=\d)(st|nd|rd|th)\b", '', str)
```

`\b` prevents things like `21strange` from being replaced.

To replace only grammatically correct constructs, you can also try:

```
re.sub(r"(?<=1\d)th\b|(?<=1)st\b|(?<=2)nd\b|(?<=3)rd\b|(?<=[04-9])th\b", r'', str)
```

This replaces `23rd` and `44th` but leaves invalid things like `23st` intact. Don't know if this is worth the trouble though.

Comment: What about `12th` and `13th`?

Comment: *"Don't know if this is worth the trouble though"* -- Yes, it's edge cases like this that make it not worth the trouble. I'd just stick to the simplest solution that works for you.